# jQuery - Simple "on('click')" Selector Issue

Tags: jquery

I have a PHP script that generates the following HTML inside a div (id="schedule_wrapper_all").

generated code:

```
<div class="appointments">
    <div class="weekday" value="2014-01-08">Wednesday 01/08</div>
    <div class="appt" value="2">
        <p class="c_name"></p>
        <div class="c_info" style="display: none;">
            <p class="c_street"></p>
            <p class="c_city"></p>
            <p class="c_time"></p>
            <p class="c_phone">Phone 1: </p>
            <p class="c_phone_alt">Phone 2: </p>
        </div>
        <div class="c_functions" style="display: none;">
            <p><button type="button" class="view_notes">View Notes</button></p>
            <p><button type="button" class="add_note">Add Note</button></p>
            <p><button type="button" class="reschedule">Reschedule</button></p>
            <p><button type="button" class="reassign">Reassign</button></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="appt" value="4">
        <p class="c_name">Mary Smith</p>
        <div class="c_info" style="display: none;">
            <p class="c_street"></p>
            <p class="c_city"></p>
            <p class="c_time"></p>
            <p class="c_phone">Phone 1: </p>
            <p class="c_phone_alt">Phone 2: </p>
        </div>
        <div class="c_functions" style="display: none;">
            <p><button type="button" class="view_notes">View Notes</button></p>
            <p><button type="button" class="add_note">Add Note</button></p>
            <p><button type="button" class="reschedule">Reschedule</button></p>
            <p><button type="button" class="reassign">Reassign</button></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="weekday" value="2014-01-10">Friday 01/10</div>
    <div class="appt" value="10">
        <p class="c_name">Nancy </p>
        <div class="c_info" style="display: none;">
            <p class="c_street">111 Main St</p>
            <p class="c_city">Ortonville</p>
            <p class="c_time">13:30:00</p>
            <p class="c_phone">Phone 1: 8101111111</p>
            <p class="c_phone_alt">Phone 2: 8109999999</p>
        </div>
        <div class="c_functions" style="display: none;">
            <p><button type="button" class="view_notes">View Notes</button></p>
            <p><button type="button" class="add_note">Add Note</button></p>
            <p><button type="button" class="reschedule">Reschedule</button></p>
            <p><button type="button" class="reassign">Reassign</button></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are multiple 'appointments', with a few buttons within each 'appt' div.  I'm trying to select the button (class="view_notes") from within the selected 'appt' div.  Here's the jQuery code I've been writing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#this_week').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'scripts/get_schedule_thisWeek.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#schedule_wrapper_all').html(data);
                $('.c_info').hide();
                $('.c_functions').hide();
            }
        });//end ajax - Fill appointments this week
    });
    
   $('#schedule_wrapper_all').on('click', '.appt', function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top},
        'slow');//end force to top
        $('.c_info', this).slideToggle();
        $('.c_functions', this).slideToggle();
    }); //Slide Toggle appointment information

=============================PROBLEMATIC AREA================================
    $('.appointments').on('click', '.view_notes', function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //Stops the slide toggle from the .item class
        alert('hello');
    });//Open Modal to view notes
});
```

As you can see, once a user selects an 'appt' div, it does a slide toggle, showing more information in two more divs (c_info and c_functions).  I need the user to be able to select the button (class="view_notes").  I can't seem to get the right selector.  I marked the area where I'm having issues.  For now, a simple "alert" will suffice.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the parent node doesn't exist yet. If that's the case, this should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.appointments .view_notes', function(e) {        
    alert('hello');
    return false; //Also cancels default behavior
});
```

If the above works, you can refine your selector (cleaner and more performant):

```
$('#schedule_wrapper_all').on('click', '.appointments .view_notes', function(e) {        
    alert('hello');
    return false; //Also cancels default behavior
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is better than return false mainly due to it not 'returning'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".appointments .view_notes").on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //Stops the slide toggle from the .item class
        alert('hello');
    });//Open Modal to view notes
```

If necessary you could even go a little stricter if you want to make sure it only effects view notes in c_function like like this

```
$(".appointments .c_functions>.view_notes").on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //Stops the slide toggle from the .item class
        alert('hello');
    });//Open Modal to view notes
```

I am assuming that that the PHP is not loading the content via AJAX since you mentioned PHP is creating the page. If it is, then you might need till success of the content load and then do you bind, since the DOM elements might still not exist.

Comment: The content is generated through AJAX.  I probably should have worded that more carefully.  The first function in the jQuery file is what populates the PHP.  I can show the PHP source if necessary.

Comment: Try placing the binding inside of the success

Comment: What I usually do is place a breakpoint in firebug right on the line of the binding. When I run the page and my breakpoint gets hit I check the elements view and see if the DOM exists. If it doesn't then nothing will get bound

Comment: Your first comment really clarified a lot for me, as I'm still new to web development.  I remember reading that the DOM element has to be present before selecting it, and AJAX would be dynamically generating the div, so it's not selectable right then and there.  Thanks for solidifying it in my mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `appointments` element also is dynamically loaded, so you need to bind the click handler to the `schedule_wrapper_all` element

```
$('#schedule_wrapper_all').on('click', '.view_notes', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); //Stops the slide toggle from the .item class
    alert('hello');
}); //Open Modal to view notes
```

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted.  I tried this before posting, and it didn't work.  Thanks for the suggestion though.