# jQuery - Selector after AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm looking for a little assistance, but mostly an explanation so I can avoid this issue in the future.

I have a PHP script that is called using AJAX.  The output of that script is as follows:

```
<div id="schedule_wrapper_all>
<div class="appointments">
    <div class="appt" value="2">
        <p class="c_name">William Davis</p>
        <div class="c_info" style="display: block;">
            <p class="c_street">230 N State Rd</p>
            <p class="c_city">Davison</p>
            <p class="c_time">11:00:00</p>
            <p class="c_phone">Phone 1: </p>
            <p class="c_phone_alt">Phone 2: </p>
        </div>
        <div class="c_functions" style="display: block;">
            <p><button type="button" class="view_notes">View Notes</button></p>
            <div class="d_view_notes" style="display: none;"></div>
            <p><button type="button" class="add_note">Add Note</button></p>
            <p><button type="button" class="reschedule">Reschedule</button></p>
            <p><button type="button" class="reassign">Reassign</button></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#schedule_wrapper_all').on('click', '.appointments .view_notes', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var leadID = $(this).closest('.appt').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'scripts/get_notes.php',
            data: {
                'leadID': leadID
            },
            success: function(data) {
//===========================PROBLEMATIC AREA=============================
                $('.d_view_notes').html(data);
                $('.d_view_notes').slideToggle();
//========================================================================
            }
        });//end ajax - Fill Notes

    });
```

get_notes.php:

```
<?php

include 'mysql_login_pdo.php';
include '../functions/db_functions.php';

$cond = array();
$params = array();

if ($_POST['leadID'] == '') {
    return;
}

if (isset($_POST['leadID']) && $_POST['leadID'] != '') {
    $leadID = $_POST['leadID'];
}
if (!empty($leadID)) {
    $cond[] = 'id_lead = ?';
    $params[] = "$leadID";
}

$query = "SELECT `leads_notes`.`message`, `leads_notes`.`created`, `status`.`status` FROM `leads_notes`,`status`";

if (count($cond)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $cond);
}
$query .= ' AND `status`.`id` = `leads_notes`.`id_status`';
$query .= ' ORDER BY `created` DESC';

//echo $query;
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);

$notes = '';

foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $row) {
    $status = $row->status;
    $message = $row->message;
    $created = $row->created;

    $notes .= '<div class="notes">';
    $notes .= "<p>$status</p>";
    $notes .= "<p>$created</p>";
    $notes .= "<p class='note_text'>$message</p>";
    $notes .= '</div><br/>';
}
$db = null;
print $notes;
```

The script works, except the `data` filled by the AJAX call fills to all divs with the class 'd_view_notes', and there are multiple on the screen.  What I want to happen is that when the button is clicked, it only fills the 'd_view_notes' contained within the selected 'appt' div.

After hours of trying, the closest I have come to getting the right selector is:

```
$(this).closest('.c_functions').children('.d_view_notes').html(data)
```

but is is not working.  I would not only appreciate the right selector, but a quick explanation of WHY I need to choose that selector.  Thanks!

If you need more information, I asked a question similar to this this morning:
[jQuery - Simple "on('click')" Selector Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070156/jquery-simple-onclick-selector-issue)

## EDIT:

I ended up adding a button to the 'c_functions' div and some jQuery to test the source code of 'd_view_notes':

```
   ...
    <p><button type="button" class="reassign">Reassign</button></p>
    <p><button type="button" id="view_source">Source</button></p>
    ...
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('#schedule_wrapper_all').on('click', '.appointments #view_source', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert($(this).closest('#schedule_wrapper_all > .appointments > .appt > .c_functions').find('.d_view_notes').html());
    }); //This works, but only after the d_view_notes div is filled
```

Once the 'd_view_notes' div is filled with text, jQuery can detect the closest 'd_view_notes' html, and show the source code fine. For some reason, I can't fill the closest 'd_view_notes' div from my previous function though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the div was not in the success callback. (credits to jakecigar).  I had to capture the button before the AJAX call (as var that), and then pass 'that' to the 'success' callback.

Working Code:

```
$('#schedule_wrapper_all').on('click', '.appointments .appt .view_notes', function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var leadID = $(this).closest('.appt').attr('value');
        var that = $(this).closest('#schedule_wrapper_all > .appointments > .appt > .c_functions').find('.d_view_notes');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'scripts/get_notes.php',
            data: {
                'leadID': leadID
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(that).html(data).slideToggle();
            }
        });//end ajax - Fill Notes
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this one work?

```
$(this).closest('.c_functions').find('.d_view_notes').html(data).slideToggle();
```

The `.closest('.c_functions')` returns the nearest `.c_functions` ancestor of the clicked button, while the `.find('.d_view_notes')` returns that element's descendants with class `d_view_notes`. Also the `slideToggle()` (as you used it) shows the element (because it currently have `display: none`)

Comment: Is there any error in your console? Maybe you have another error somewhere else, which affects the rest of the script.

Comment: It doesn't look like there are any errors in the console.  The funny thing is, if I allow AJAX to fill all of the divs with the '.d_view_item' class, it works without issues.  It only fails to work when trying to get the currently selected 'appt' div.

Comment: I added 'get_notes.php', which is the script that is called using AJAX to the first post.